# Past perfect / present perfect

Tags: past-tense, perfect-constructions

Which one is correct?

> I had wet.
>   I had got wet.
>   I have wet.
>   I have got wet.

Comment: All of them are grammatical! Some of them almost certainly don't mean what you intended. But you didn't explain what you intended, so if you can add some more detail we can help you more!

Comment: @TypeIA - I'm having trouble seeing the first and third as grammatical, although they could certainly be grammatical in the context of a longer expression or phrase.

Comment: @J.R. "To wet" is a verb, and I suppose we could debate whether a direct object is strictly required grammatically, but I'd argue it can be implied with context. The most likely implication I can think of is _to wet the bed_ or _to wet one's pants_ but as a parent of two young children I might be biased...

Comment: @TypeIA - Yeah, that's what I was thinking; I think those need an object: _I had wet my fingers, I had wet the bed, I had wet the whetstone_, etc. [Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/wet) expects an object, too.